# Missing valid YouTube API key

Tags: html, reactjs, api, youtube

I tried connecting my app to YouTube v3 API but it's showing me the request has no valid API key, I have doubled checked the API key, but it's still giving me the warning. Here is the code.

```
import axios from "axios";
const KEY = "MY_Key Here";
export default axios.create({
baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
params: {
 part: "snippet",
 maxResults: 5,
 key: KEY,
},
});
```

The app js code

```
 const response = await youtube.get("/search", {
   params: {
     q: searchQuery
   },
 });
 console.log(response);
};
```

it says "the request is missing valid api key" domain="Global" reason-"forbidden" and status="Denied".